# как удалить в строке все буквы и цифры кроме символов с помощью реглярных выражений

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

есть метод на вход принимает строку надо убрать буквы и цифры, не могу регулярное выражение правильно выставить  `private static String REGEX = "[A-z-0-9]+";

```
public static void isNotLetter(String simbol ) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(simbol);

    while (!matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(simbol);
    }`
```

Comment: Вы понимаете, что ваш код для поиска, а не для удаления? Вам нужно использовать `.replaceAll`. Похоже, этот метод - лишь часть более длинного кода, без которого невозможно дать верный ответ. Пожалуйста, приведите весь код.

Answer (score 0):

Сто раз уже было:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]
```

А ещё лучше

```
\w
```

или

```
(?!_)\w
```

---

Для того, чтобы удалить - наоборот:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]
(?!\w).
_|(?!\w).
```

```
String res = str.replaceAll("_|(?!\w).", "");
```

Comment: Данные примеры никак не смогут помочь *удалить* специальные символы, так как основаня проблема в данном случае — это ошиька в программной логике. Кстати, если вы видели решение раньше, пожалуйста, закройте вопрос как дубликат, не за чем публиковать повторные ответы.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, но в вопросе не удаление, а поиск и вывод всех вхождений. Впрочем, дополнил.

Comment: На этот вопрос нельзя дать ответ без дополнительной информации.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, не согласен.

Comment: В любом случае, регулярные выражения не удаляют текст, они лишь служат для того, чтобы с помощью некоторых программных методов *найти* текст, соответствующий выражению. Удалить же может именно такой метод, но не само выражение.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, для удаления надо взять метод замены и заменить все вхождения на пустую строку. Мне кажется, это очевидно. Дополнил.